# following packages have unmet dependencies: ros-indigo-desktop-full

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

which broken packages are being considered by the system ? Help me to solve this.

neel

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree Reading state information... 
Done Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. 

The following information may help to resolve the situation: The following packages have unmet dependencies: ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-simulators but it is not going to be installed 

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222828/following-packages-have-unmet-dependencies:-ros-indigo-desktop-full/) by [Neel](https://answers.ros.org/users/25346/neel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-12-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2015-12-19**:
Thanks 130s for formatting the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears that you are missing the package `ros-indigo-simulators`. This could be because of two things, either you

A) didn't properly set up your ROS installation environment. Or,

B) the package isn't normally installed but you still need it.

Based on the two above problems, here are two solutions.
First you could try installing `ros-indigo-simulators` through apt by running the command `$sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-simulators`. If that doesn't work you may need to go through the installation guide on the wiki again(http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/)
Hope that helps!

---

Originally posted by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) with karma: 285 on 2015-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0